# Unable to convert JSON array containing nested objects to POJO arraylist

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, gson

Good day all, i'am developing app in android and i have to be able to recieve JSON array and convert it to plain old POJO arraylist.I'm using GSON to do this i.e.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<AccountTypesRegistered> list = gson.fromJson(responseBody.string(),
                            new TypeToken<ArrayList<AccountTypesRegistered>>() {
                            }.getType());
```

however if i try to do:

```
try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                            AccountTypesRegistered checklist = list.get(i);

                            Log.e("JsonObject", checklist.toString());

                            Log.e("Name", checklist.getClientNames());
}
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

i get this error message in logcat:

```
12-16 03:31:44.371: E/JsonObject(5121): com.nickSoft.dbhelper.AccountTypesRegistered@41d73610
12-16 03:31:44.371: W/System.err(5121): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
12-16 03:31:44.371: W/System.err(5121):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
12-16 03:31:44.371: W/System.err(5121):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:232)
12-16 03:31:44.371: W/System.err(5121):     at com.nickSoft.Connections.OkHttpHandlerIncoming$1.onResponse(OkHttpHandlerIncoming.java:91)
12-16 03:31:44.371: W/System.err(5121):     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:126)
12-16 03:31:44.371: W/System.err(5121):     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
12-16 03:31:44.371: W/System.err(5121):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-16 03:31:44.371: W/System.err(5121):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-16 03:31:44.371: W/System.err(5121):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here is my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "AccountType": "15516321",
    "CustomerName": "1MACMONSAM NICOLAS",
    "Currentbalance": "1100,000.00",
    "AccountKey": "",
    "AllTransactions": [
      {
        "ID": 103,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5001",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:40",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 105,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5002",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 107,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5003",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 109,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5004",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 111,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5005",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 113,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5006",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 115,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5007",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 117,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5008",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 119,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5009",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 121,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "50010",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 103,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "01",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 105,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "02",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 107,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "03",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 109,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "04",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 111,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "05",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 113,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "06",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 115,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "07",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 117,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "08",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 119,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "09",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 121,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "010",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 103,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5001",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 105,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5002",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 107,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5003",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 109,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5004",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 111,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5005",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 113,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5006",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 115,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5007",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 117,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5008",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 119,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5009",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 121,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "50010",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "AccountType": "25526322",
    "CustomerName": "2MACMONSAM NICOLAS",
    "Currentbalance": "2100,000.00",
    "AccountKey": "",
    "AllTransactions": [
      {
        "ID": 103,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5001",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:40",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 105,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5002",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 107,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5003",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 109,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5004",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 111,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5005",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 113,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5006",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 115,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5007",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 117,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5008",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 119,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5009",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 121,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "50010",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 103,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "01",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 105,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "02",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 107,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "03",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 109,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "04",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 111,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "05",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 113,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "06",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 115,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "07",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 117,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "08",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 119,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "09",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 121,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "010",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 103,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5001",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 105,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5002",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 107,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5003",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 109,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5004",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 111,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5005",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 113,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5006",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 115,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5007",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 117,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5008",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 119,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5009",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 121,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "50010",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "AccountType": "35536323",
    "CustomerName": "3MACMONSAM NICOLAS",
    "Currentbalance": "3100,000.00",
    "AccountKey": "",
    "AllTransactions": [
      {
        "ID": 103,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5001",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:40",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 105,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5002",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 107,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5003",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 109,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5004",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 111,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5005",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 113,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5006",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 115,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5007",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 117,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5008",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 119,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "5009",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 121,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I need money right now",
        "Debit": "50010",
        "Credit": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      },
      {
        "ID": 103,
        "DescriptionoOfTransaction": "I'am putting in money right now",
        "Debit": "01",
        "Credit": "1500",
        "TransactionDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41",
        "ValueDate": "16/12/2016 16:42:41"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and the classes:

```
public class AccountTypesRegistered {

    private String ClientNames;
    private String AccountTypesOwnedByClient;
    private ArrayList<AccountActivityObject> AccountsActivity;
    private String AccountBalance;
    private String AccountKey;

    public AccountTypesRegistered() {

    }

    ////////////////////////// SETTERS HERE///////////////////////////////////
    public void setAccountTypesOwnedByClient(String AccountTypes) {

        this.AccountTypesOwnedByClient = AccountTypes;
    }

    public void setAccountsActivity(ArrayList<AccountActivityObject> AccountsAct) {
        this.AccountsActivity = AccountsAct;
    }

    public void setClientNames(String Clientna) {
        this.ClientNames = Clientna;
    }

    public void setAccountBalance(String AccountBal) {
        this.AccountBalance = AccountBal;
    }

    public void setAccountKey(String Acctkey) {

        this.AccountKey = Acctkey;
    }

    /////////////////////// GETTERS
    /////////////////////// HERE////////////////////////////////////////////
    public String getClientNames() {
        return this.ClientNames;
    }

    public String getAccountTypesOwnedByClient() {
        return this.AccountTypesOwnedByClient;
    }

    public ArrayList<AccountActivityObject> getAccountsActivity() {
        return this.AccountsActivity;
    }

    public String getAccountBalance() {
        return this.AccountBalance;
    }

    public String getAccountKey() {
        return this.AccountKey;
    }
}

public class AccountActivityObject implements Parcelable {

    private String IdOfTransaction;
    private String DescriptionOftransaction;
    private String ValueDate;
    private String DateofTransaction;
    private String Debit;
    private String Credit;
    private String Closing;
    private String TransactionLinkToAccountKey;

    public AccountActivityObject() {

    }

    /**
     * Use when reconstructing User object from parcel This will be used only by
     * the 'CREATOR'
     * 
     * @param in
     *            a parcel to read this object
     */
    public AccountActivityObject(Parcel in) {

        this.DescriptionOftransaction = in.readString();
        this.IdOfTransaction = in.readString();
        this.ValueDate = in.readString();
        this.DateofTransaction = in.readString();
        this.Debit = in.readString();
        this.Credit = in.readString();
        this.Closing = in.readString();
        this.TransactionLinkToAccountKey = in.readString();

    }

    /**
     * Define the kind of object that you gonna parcel, You can use hashCode()
     * here
     */
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Actual object serialization happens here, Write object content to parcel
     * one by one, reading should be done according to this write order
     * 
     * @param dest
     *            parcel
     * @param flags
     *            Additional flags about how the object should be written
     */
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeString(DescriptionOftransaction);
        dest.writeString(IdOfTransaction);
        dest.writeString(ValueDate);
        dest.writeString(DateofTransaction);
        dest.writeString(Debit);
        dest.writeString(Credit);
        dest.writeString(Closing);
        dest.writeString(TransactionLinkToAccountKey);

    }

    /**
     * This field is needed for Android to be able to create new objects,
     * individually or as arrays
     *
     * If you don’t do that, Android framework will through exception Parcelable
     * protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR
     */
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<AccountActivityObject> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<AccountActivityObject>() {

        public AccountActivityObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new AccountActivityObject(in);
        }

        public AccountActivityObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new AccountActivityObject[size];
        }
    };

    // use this to text for equality of objects
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof AccountActivityObject) {
            AccountActivityObject toCompare = (AccountActivityObject) obj;
            return (this.IdOfTransaction.equalsIgnoreCase(toCompare.getIdOfTransaction()));
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (this.getIdOfTransaction()).hashCode();
    }

    ///////////////// SET METHODS/////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void setIdOfTransaction(String IDoftransaction) {
        IdOfTransaction = IDoftransaction;
    }

    public void setDescriptionOftransaction(String Descriptiontransaction) {
        DescriptionOftransaction = Descriptiontransaction;
    }

    public void setValueDate(String ValueDateTransaction) {
        ValueDate = ValueDateTransaction;
    }

    public void setDateofTransaction(String DateTransaction) {
        DateofTransaction = DateTransaction;
    }

    // set Debit if available
    public void setDebit(String DebitAmt) {
        Debit = DebitAmt;
    }

    // set Credit
    public void setCredit(String CreditAmt) {
        Credit = CreditAmt;
    }

    // Always set closing
    public void setClosing(String ClosingAmt) {
        Closing = ClosingAmt;
    }

    public void setTransactionLinkToAccountKey(String TransacLinkToAccountKey) {
        TransactionLinkToAccountKey = TransacLinkToAccountKey;

    }

    ///////////////// GET METHODS/////////////////////////////////////////////

    public String getValueDate() {

        return ValueDate;
    }

    public String getDateofTransaction() {
        return DateofTransaction;
    }

    public String getIdOfTransaction() {
        return IdOfTransaction;
    }

    public String getDescriptionOftransaction() {
        return DescriptionOftransaction;
    }

    // get show Debit if available
    public String getDebit() {
        return Debit;
    }

    // get show Credit if available
    public String getCredit() {
        return Credit;
    }

    // get show Closing
    public String getClosing() {
        return Closing;
    }

    public String getTransactionLinkToAccountKey() {

        return TransactionLinkToAccountKey;
    }
}
```

Please how to solve the problem and get my arraylist from the JSON. Any help is welcome

Comment: Generate POJO Class using your JSON with help here -http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: it might help you

Comment: @ Maharith thanks for the heads up

Comment: You Welcome. Hope I helped a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model class is wrong.. You should have same variable names as the key of json. Like for CustomerName you should have CustomerName as variable in your model class. 
Or
Use this http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ . It converts you json to POJO...

Answer (score 0):

Is this `POST` or `response`? Your JSON looks fine. Not familiar with the API but I think it may be one of four things:

1. If posting you may want to convert this into a javascript object not a JSON object.

   AccountType:"15516321",CustomerName:"1MACMONSAM NICOLAS",Currentbalance:"1100,000.00",AccountKey:"", ...
2. You may have exceeded the amount of data based on how you are sending/receiving the object.
3. If you look in your dev console is the JSON string erroring out? If the string object is bad the dev console typically tells you. Maybe you have to encode the object.
4. Your class is not properly defined so it cannot handle the data

**EDIT**

Since this is a response you will be able to determine whether or not your server-side class object is handling the data correctly. Since you have nested array I am almost guessing the class object needs its properties updated. If it makes it to your browser you can see the object using Dev Console which I doubt that is the cas since your stack trace identifies the issue.

Comment: No problem. Have you ever used fiddler? I suggest you install the plugin using chrome. It shows you your http requests/responses including header info and statuses

Comment: I almost betting that the nested array `private ArrayList<AccountActivityObject> AccountsActivity;` doesn't match up with `AllActivity: [{},{}]`. Maybe all you need is a `<List>` and it needs to be nullable too!

Answer (score 0):

The Json does not contain ClientNames field and hence it would be populated as null in the deserialized Object.

From your log the following line throws Null Pointer as its previous statement is logged properly.
 Log.e("Name", checklist.getClientNames());

This means that Log.e function gets checklist.getClientNames() as null and throws NPE while trying to work on it.

Try adding the ClientNames field in JSon and it would work fine.